# detect user logging out of Facebook on the browser and unsetting session variable in Symfony app

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I am working on a Symfony app where users can link their Facebook account by connecting to it. When the authentication succeeds, I update the session by setting the ‘facebook_user’ field to the current Facebook user I get as a response from the authentication flow.

However, when the user logs out of Facebook on the same browser where they’re using my app, they are also logged out of Facebook on my app (I’m relying on Facebook’s API authentication and would like to keep it that way). However, my session still indicates that there’s a Facebook account connected.

I would like to detect when the user logs out of Facebook on the browser and trigger an action to unset the ‘facebook_user’ field in the session. Is there a way to do this using the Facebook SDK for JavaScript or some other method?

I tried detecting when the user logs out of Facebook on the browser using a combination of the Facebook SDK for JavaScript and jQuery. Here is the code I used:

```html
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId            : 'xxxxxxxx',
            autoLogAppEvents : true,
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v17.0'
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
            // Send AJAX request to unset session variable
            console.log("disconnected");
            $.post('/unset/session', function(data) {
                // Session variable unset
            });
        });
    };
</script>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

In this code, I’m using the **`FB.Event.subscribe()`** function to subscribe to the **`auth.logout`** event and trigger a callback function when the event occurs. When the **`auth.logout`** event is triggered, I’m sending an AJAX request to a route in my Symfony app to unset the session variable.

However, it looks like the logout is not being detected since nothing shows up on the console when I log out of Facebook on the browser. Is there something wrong with my code or is there a better way to detect when the user logs out of Facebook on the browser?